# MySQL vs PostgreSQL in Django, from locks point of view

Tags: mysql, django, postgresql

I've been searching the web for some time now and can't come to a conclusion.

When working with Django project and MySQL I came across a DEADLOCK problem that I assume caused by the "Next-Key" locking in MySQL.

After some search it seems that PostgreSQL doesn't use  this locking mechanism, so it will solve me this issue, but I have some doubts because I dont fully understand the locking of PostgreSQL, also I am not sure what are the ramifications from performance point of view.

I would be glad if you could explain the locking in PostgreSQL for me, or maybe give me another ideas to research. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

InnoDB takes a next-key lock only if you `SELECT` with `FOR UPDATE` or `LOCK IN SHARE MODE` in `REPEATABLE READ` (the default value) or `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level.

PostgreSQL doesn't lock any gaps; rows that are later inserted in a gap by a concurrent transaction simply are not visible by the `REPEATABLE READ` transaction, so the problem just doesn't exist.

I don't know why MySQL has a problem with that since any InnoDB table has a field `DB_TRX_ID` that stores the transaction that created the row, but then I cannot claim to be a MySQL expert.